# rsyncing files based on size

Tags: linux, rsync

I am trying to `rsync` files with the extension `*.scala` and only those no other files between two directories. If the size is different they should be synced and the operation should be recursive. I am executing this command and seeing no scala files being synced even though I know the sizes are different.

```
rsync -rnvh --ignore-times --size-only --include '*/' --include '*.scala' --exclude '*' /home/salilsurendran/code/servlet-app /home/salilsurendran/code/sbt-runs/servlet-app/
```

With the `-n` option I am doing a dry run and the output prints out a bunch of directories but not any files. Please help

Comment: My suggestion would be to read (at least) the filter rule section of the `rsync` manual (page).

Comment: Try with this syntax and let me know if that gives you the expected result: `rsync -rvh --size-only --include="*/" --include="*.scala" --exclude="*" /home/salilsurendran/code/servlet-app/ /home/salilsurendran/code/sbt-runs/servlet-app/`. . . If so I'll be happy to add an answer with more detail explaining what appears to be the problem.

Comment: Why did you add the star to your question? Was it a typo? Did you have the problem without the star? Do you still have the problem with the star? "Added 1 char" is not a meaningful description for an edit.

Answer (score 0):

rsync -nrvh --size-only --include="*/" --include="*.scala" --exclude="*" /home/salilsurendran/code/servlet-app/ /home/salilsurendran/code/sbt-runs/servlet-app/.

the issue was with the trailing '/' at the end of the from directory. Adding that made it work as I expected. Thanks.